# Readthedocs custom domain stops working with ssl issue

Tags: ssl, read-the-docs

I got problems with my custom domain setup on readthedocs.
Suddenly custom domain (https://docs.joinrpg.ru) stops working with SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP.

Variois SSL checkers report that they "`Failed to communicate with the secure server`".

Readthedocs panel say that  `SSL certificate status: restricted_name_failure: Use of one or more domains on the certificate is restricted`.

There was partial [block](https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues/8966) by local authorities of readthedocs in Russia, but it (a) was on DNS-level (b)seems to be solved now, and (c) problem seems to reproduce outside russia.

What can I do to diagnose issue?

Comment: Something related to networking and regulation (Russia related assets are under a lot of sanctions at this moment) does not fall under Stack Overflow

Comment: Seems not related to network and regulation. Opened bug against readthedocs https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues/9149

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug with Cloudflare doesn't allow to issue certificates for "ru" domain zone.
It have been switched to Let's encrypt thanks to readthedocs team.

https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues/9149